# Socket.io is initialised but emit and on not working

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Socket is getting initialised but no client id is coming in console log ...I m not able to debug the problem if it is on server side or client side.Please help to find out the mistake.Room is created properly and client got added but i can't see any client id in console.I feel the problem could be on server side. I am really frustrated and tried to solve it but there is no error showing anywhere on console.

**Server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
// const path = require("path");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const ACTIONS = require("./src/Actions");
const cors = require('cors');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server);
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: '*'}));
// app.use(express.static("build"));
// app.use((req, res, next) => {
//   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "build", "index.html"));
// });

const userSocketMap = {};

function getAllConnectedClients(roomId) {
  // Map
  return Array.from(io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(roomId) || []).map(
    (socketId) => {
      return {
        socketId,
        username: userSocketMap[socketId],
      };
    }
  );
}

//This console is not working
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("socket connected", socket.id);
  socket.on(ACTIONS.JOIN, ({ roomId, username }) => {
    console.log("this is worjing...")
    userSocketMap[socket.id] = username;
    socket.join(roomId);
    const clients = getAllConnectedClients(roomId);
    clients.forEach(({ socketId }) => {
      io.to(socketId).emit(ACTIONS.JOINED, {
        clients,
        username,
        socketId: socket.id,
      });
    });
  });
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`));
```

**Client.js**

```
const EditorPage = () => {
  const socketRef = useRef(null);
  const codeRef = useRef(null);
  const location = useLocation();
  const reactNavigator = useNavigate();
  const { roomId } = useParams();
  const [clients, setClients] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const init = async () => {
      
      socketRef.current = await initSocket();
      
      socketRef.current.on("connect_error", (err) => handleErrors(err));
      socketRef.current.on("connect_failed", (err) => handleErrors(err));

      function handleErrors(e) {
        console.log("socket error", e);
        toast.error("Socket connection failed, try again later.");
        reactNavigator("/");
      }
      //I guess if it is working or not
      socketRef.current.emit(ACTIONS.JOIN, {
        roomId,
        username: location.state?.username,
        
      });
      
      
      //Listening for joined event
      socketRef.current.on(
        ACTIONS.JOINED,
        ({ clients, username, socketId }) => {
          if (username !== location.state?.username) {
            toast.success(`${username} joined the room.`);
            console.log(`${username} joined`);
          }
          console.log(clients);
          setClients(clients);

          socketRef.current.emit(ACTIONS.SYNC_CODE, {
            code: codeRef.current,
            socketId,
          });
        }
      );
```

Socket.js

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

export const initSocket = async () => {

  // console.log('socket init');
  const options = {
    "force new connection": true,
    reconnectionAttempt: Infinity,
    timeout: 10000,
    transports: ["websocket"],
  };
  console.log("working")
  return io(process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL, options);
};
```

//it is working fine